# Expand _In_ to const

Tags: c++, const-correctness, sal

Except for the fact, that it would probably *confuse* every windows c++ developer out there,

wouldn't it be prudent to expand `_In_` to a mandatory `const` (if not already present) to ensure const correctness?

So

```
int DoSomething( _In_ int * pInput);
```

becomes

```
int DoSomething( const int * pInput);
```

Obviously _[In]Out_ should still expand to *nothing*.

---

**Edit**: Obviously the first problem is that, this only makes sense when expanding *in front* of a pointer or a reference parameter.

So maybe a simpke macro expansion will not suffice. I don't want to abandon the notion of enforcing `const` just yet. The motto is: We already have a `SAL` notation that tells us what parameter is `ro` and what not, let's make some use of it.

Comment: Isn't the real question, why is the argument a pointer in the first place?

Comment: No. But rather, can I (in cooperation with the precompiler) determine whether the following argument really is a pointer.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I don't think `boost::optional<>` made it into the C++11 specification (though [cppreference has a related entry?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional), so what convenient alternative is there for passing an optional argument that doesn't have a convenient sentinel value, and why is it always better?

Comment: @TonyD: `optional` didn't make it, not even in 14. But SAL has a separate annotation for "this is a pointer because it's optional": `_In_opt_`. Since the argument in the example is just `_In_`, I was curious.

Comment: @MrPaulch The preprocessor will never cooperate with you, especially not on matters of types, since it operates purely on tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a macro expansion, that wouldn't work for values copied into parameters, i.e.

```
void f( _In_ X x) { g(++x); // ok to modify }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should train your programmers to use `const` for pointer/reference parameters that are intended to be immutable, even if the SAL annotation is used.

Here are some problems with expanding `_In_` to `const`:

- Programmers who haven't seen SAL annotations before are extra confused.
- These programmers will then write `_In const int*` and possibly get a compiler error, depending on whether the compiler diagnoses double const.
- It's annoying for by-value parameters that the programmer wants to modify inside the function.
- It's catastrophic for COM interface pointers. COM interfaces never have `const` members (because that's a very C++-specific thing). This means that a pointer to a const interface is absolutely useless. But you will still, quite often, pass `_In_` or `_In_opt_` parameters of interface type.